# Nginx SSL locations keeps redirecting

Tags: nginx, ssl, redirect

My site's been running fine on nginx for years. Have SSL and non-SSL locations. PHP runs through .shtml files

Working on a Facebook app and right now need to have it work with both the SSL and non-SSL URL. Testing the coding on my server right now. I can't get it to work in the SSL config.

If I go to http://www.example.com/myappsname the page loads.

https://www.example.com/myappsname/index.shtml the page loads. <-note https

https://www.example.com/myappsname/ the page tosses a 404

Here are the relevant locations in the SSL server section:

```
location / {
root /usr/local/apache/htdocs;
rewrite ^(.+) http://www.example.com$1 permanent;
index index.shtml index.php;
}

location ~ \.(shtml|php|inc)$ {
root /usr/local/apache/htdocs;
include /usr/local/nginx/conf/fastcgi-php.conf;
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:10004;
}

location ^~ /myappsname/ {
index index.shtml;
root /usr/local/apache/htdocs/;
fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
include /usr/local/nginx/conf/fastcgi-php.conf;
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:10004;
fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
}
```

I'll probably smack my head when this is pointed out to me. All my other SSL locations work fine. Any idea why including the filename stays SSL but dropping it redirects?

Comment: What's there in fastcgi-php.conf? It can be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

With the config that you've provided, `https://www.example.com/myappsname/` does not redirect, however, `https://www.example.com/myappsname` does, as it doesn't match the prefix search of `location ^~ /myappsname/`.

Your description uses a trailing slash for the HTTPS URL, but none on the HTTP URL - I'm guessing that this isn't quite accurate, and that you're seeing the redirect improperly occurring only when the trailing slash is absent from the HTTPS URL.

If this is the case, fix your prefix match - drop the trailing slash, or just set up a `location = /myappsname`?

Comment: Just did another test location ^~ /myappsname/, location ^~ /myappsname and location /myappsname/ all resulted in a 404. Really hurting my head...the other ssl locations are fine. :-(

Comment: @Ian That's not hitting the redirect in the `/` location block, so, that's what we're going for..  are your `root` and `index` directives for your test block set up to serve up the right page in the test `location`?  Maybe just use `location = /myappsname` for testing to be absolutely sure of which config you're hitting..

Comment: changing to location = /myappsname stops the 404 but now redirects to the http version, which doesn't fit in with facebook's move to ssl. Still don't understand why this location isn't working but the other ssl locations are. A real head scratcher.

Comment: Looking at the debug log a call to /myappsname isn't matching the /myappsname location. Sigh...